# Import Excel Xls with phpspreadsheet di Laravel 9 only one data entry being imported per operation

Tags: excel, laravel-9, phpspreadsheet, import-from-excel

I want to import data from Excel to Laravel using Laravel 9 and PhpSpreadsheet 1.19. However, I'm facing an issue where, for example, there are 248 data rows in the Excel file, plus 1 row for headers. The function I created only processes 1 data row at a time for each import operation, and so on. So, out of the 248 data rows, only 1 data row will be imported in the first import, and in the second import as well, only 1 data row will be imported. This pattern continues for subsequent imports, resulting in only one data entry  being imported per operation.
Here is the modal form:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="Modalss" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="smallModal" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Import Data Excel</h4>
            </div>
            <form action="importdata" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                @csrf
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="form-group">
                
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <input type="file" required class="form-control-file" name="uploaded_file" id="uploaded_file">
                        </div>
                        <small class="form-text text-muted">Please upload only Excel (.xlsx or .xls) files.</small>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Import Data</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is the function for importing the data:

```
public function importdataexcels(Request $request)
{
    try{
        $request->validate([
            'uploaded_file' => 'required|mimes:xls,xlsx',
        ]);
    
        $importer = new DataImport();
        $importer->importDataExcel($request);

       
        $pesan = "Data diimport ke Absensi &nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;:  <strong>" . $importer->getJumlahDataDiimport() . "</strong>" . "<br>" .
        "Data diimport ke Tidak Masuk: <strong>" . $importer->getDataImportTidakMasuk() . "</strong>" . "<br>" .
        "Data tidak bisa diimport &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;: <strong>" . $importer->getDatatTidakBisaDiimport() . "</strong>" . "<br>" .
        "Jumlah Data Keseluruhan &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;: <strong>" . $importer->getJumlahData(). "</strong>";
        // return $pesan;
    
        $pesan = '<div class="text-left" style="margin-left: 75px;">' . $pesan . '</div>';
        // return $pesan;
        $pesan = nl2br(html_entity_decode($pesan));
        return redirect()->back()->with('pesan', $pesan);

    }catch (\Throwable $th) {
       
        return redirect()->back()->with('pesa', 'Terjadi kesalahan saat mengimport data dari Excel.');
    }
    
}
```

This is class **DataImport.php:**

```
<?php

 namespace App\Imports;
 use Carbon\Carbon;
 use App\Models\Cuti;
 use App\Models\Izin;
 use App\Models\Absensi;
 use App\Models\Karyawan;
 use App\Models\Jeniscuti;
 use App\Models\Jenisizin;
 use App\Models\Tidakmasuk;
 use Illuminate\Http\Request;
 use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;
 use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory;

 class DataImport
 {

private $jumlahdatadiimport = 0;
private $jumlahdata = 0; //jumlah data keseluruhan
private $jumlahimporttidakmasuk = 0;
private $datatidakbisadiimport = 0; //JUMLAH DATA TIDAK DIIMPORT

public function importDataExcel(Request $request)
{
    $file = $request->file('uploaded_file');
    $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
    
    $reader = null;
    if ($extension === 'xls') {
        $reader = IOFactory::createReader('Xls');
    } elseif ($extension === 'xlsx') {
        $reader = IOFactory::createReader('Xlsx');
    }

    if ($reader === null) {
        // Handle unsupported file extension
    }
    
    $spreadsheet = $reader->load($file);        
    
    $worksheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
    $data = $worksheet->toArray();
    
    $header = $data[0];
   
    for ($i = 1; $i < count($data); $i++) 
    {
        // Ambil data pada baris saat ini
        $rowData = $data[$i];
        // Buat array asosiatif menggunakan header sebagai kunci
        $row = [];
        for ($j = 0; $j < count($rowData); $j++) {
            $row[$header[$j]] = $rowData[$j];
        }
         // dd($row);
        if (isset($row['NIK']) && isset($row['Tanggal'])) 
        {
            $this->jumlahdata++;
            $karyawan = Karyawan::where('nik', $row['NIK'])->first();
            
            if(isset($karyawan))
            {
                $tgl = \Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $row['Tanggal'])->format('Y-m-d');
                // dd($row,$tgl);
                $absensicek = !Absensi::where('id_karyawan',$karyawan->id)->where('tanggal',$tgl)->first();
                
                if($absensicek)
                {
                    $scan_masuk = $row['Scan Masuk'];
                    $scan_pulang= $row['Scan Pulang']; 

                    if($scan_masuk === "" && $scan_pulang === "")
                    {
                        $cuti = Cuti::where('id_karyawan', $karyawan->id)
                            ->whereDate('tgl_mulai', '<=', $tgl)
                            ->whereDate('tgl_selesai', '>=', $tgl)
                            ->where('status', 7)
                            ->select('cuti.id as id_cuti','cuti.id_karyawan','cuti.id_jeniscuti','cuti.tgl_mulai','cuti.tgl_selesai','cuti.status')
                            ->first();

                        $nama = Karyawan::where('id',$karyawan->id)->select('nama','divisi')->first();
                        
                        if($cuti !== NULL) 
                        {

                            $reason = Jeniscuti::where('id',$cuti->id_jeniscuti)->select('jenis_cuti')->first();

                            for($date = Carbon::parse($cuti->tgl_mulai);$date->lte(Carbon::parse($cuti->tgl_selesai)); $date->addDay())
                            {
                                $cek = Tidakmasuk::where('id_pegawai', $cuti->id_karyawan)->where('tanggal', $date->format('Y-m-d'))->first();
                                if(!$cek){
                                    $tidakmasuk = new Tidakmasuk;
                                    $tidakmasuk->id_pegawai = $cuti->id_karyawan;
                                    $tidakmasuk->nama       = $nama->nama;
                                    $tidakmasuk->divisi     = $nama->divisi;
                                    $tidakmasuk->status     = $reason->jenis_cuti;
                                    $tidakmasuk->tanggal    = $date->format('Y-m-d');

                                    // dd($tidakmasuk);
                                    $tidakmasuk->save();

                                    $this->jumlahimporttidakmasuk++;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $izin = Izin::where('id_karyawan','=',$karyawan->id)
                                ->whereDate('tgl_mulai', '<=', $tgl)
                                ->whereDate('tgl_selesai', '>=', $tgl)
                                ->where('status',7)
                                ->select('izin.id','izin.id_karyawan','izin.id_jenisizin','izin.tgl_mulai','izin.tgl_selesai','izin.status')
                                ->first();
                            // dd($izin);
                            if($izin !== NULL)
                            {
                                // dd($izin);
                                //selain 5 karena id 5 itu
                                if($izin->id_jenisizin !== 5)
                                {
                                    $reason = Jenisizin::where('id',$izin->id_jenisizin)->select('jenis_izin')->first();

                                    for($date = Carbon::parse($izin->tgl_mulai);$date->lte(Carbon::parse($izin->tgl_selesai)); $date->addDay())
                                    {
                                        $cek = Tidakmasuk::where('id_pegawai', $izin->id_karyawan)->where('tanggal', $date->format('Y-m-d'))->first();
                                        if(!$cek)
                                        {
                                            $tidakmasuk = new Tidakmasuk;
                                            $tidakmasuk->id_pegawai = $izin->id_karyawan;
                                            $tidakmasuk->nama       = $nama->nama;
                                            $tidakmasuk->divisi     = $nama->divisi;
                                            $tidakmasuk->status     = $reason->jenis_izin;
                                            $tidakmasuk->tanggal    = $date->format('Y-m-d');
                                            $tidakmasuk->save();

                                            $this->jumlahimporttidakmasuk++;
                                            
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                // dd($izin);
                                $cek = Tidakmasuk::where('id_pegawai', $karyawan->id)->where('tanggal',$tgl)->first();
                                // dd($cek);
                                //jika tidak ada data atau $cek == null
                                if(!$cek)
                                {
                                    // dd($cek);
                                    $nama = Karyawan::where('nik',$row['NIK'])->first();
                                    dd($nama);
                                    $tidakmasuk = new Tidakmasuk;
                                    $tidakmasuk->id_pegawai = $nama->id;
                                    $tidakmasuk->nama       = $nama->nama;
                                    $tidakmasuk->divisi     = $nama->divisi;
                                    $tidakmasuk->status     = 'tanpa keterangan';
                                    $tidakmasuk->tanggal    = $tgl;
                            
                                    // dd($tidakmasuk);
                                    $tidakmasuk->save();
                                    // dd($tidakmasuk);

                                    $this->jumlahimporttidakmasuk++;
                                    Log::info('Data '. $row['NIK'] . $row['Tanggal']. ' berhasil diimport ke Tidak Masuk');
                                }
                                else{
                                    $this->datatidakbisadiimport++;
                                    // dd($cek);
                                    Log::info('Data tidak masuk karyawan sudah ada');
                                }
                            } 
                        } 
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // dd($data);
                        $jam_excel = [
                            'Jam Masuk'   => $row['Jam Masuk'],
                            'Jam Pulang'  => $row['Jam Pulang'],
                            'Scan Masuk'  => $row['Scan Masuk'],
                            'Scan Pulang' => $row['Scan Pulang'],
                            'Terlambat'   => $row['Terlambat'],
                            'Plg. Cepat'  => $row['Plg. Cepat'],
                            'Lembur'      => $row['Lembur'],
                            'Jml Jam Kerja'   => $row['Jml Jam Kerja'],
                            'Jml Kehadiran'   => $row['Jml Kehadiran'],
                        ];
                       
                        $formatted_jam = [];
                    
                        foreach ($jam_excel as $key => $value) {
                            if (!empty($value)) {
                                $time = Carbon::createFromFormat('H.i', $value); // Create Carbon instance from the time string
                                $formatted_jam[$key] = $time->format('H:i:s'); // Format the time as HH:MM:SS
                            } else {
                                $formatted_jam[$key] = null; // Assign null if the value is empty
                            }
                        }
                        // dd($jam_excel,$formatted_jam);
                        $data = [
                            'id_karyawan'   => $karyawan->id,
                            'nik'           => $karyawan->nip ?? null,
                            'tanggal'       => $tgl,
                            'shift'         => null,
                            'jadwal_masuk'  => isset($formatted_jam['Jam Masuk']) ? $formatted_jam['Jam Masuk'] : null,
                            'jadwal_pulang' => isset($formatted_jam['Jam Pulang']) ? $formatted_jam['Jam Pulang'] : null,
                            'jam_masuk'     => isset($formatted_jam['Scan Masuk']) ? $formatted_jam['Scan Masuk'] : null,
                            'jam_keluar'    => isset($formatted_jam['Scan Pulang']) ? $formatted_jam['Scan Pulang'] : null,
                            'normal'        => null,
                            'riil'          => null,
                            'terlambat'     => isset($formatted_jam['Terlambat']) ? $formatted_jam['Terlambat'] : null,
                            'plg_cepat'     => isset($formatted_jam['Plg. Cepat']) ? $formatted_jam['Plg. Cepat'] : null,
                            'absent'        => null,
                            'lembur'        => isset($formatted_jam['Lembur']) ? $formatted_jam['Lembur'] : null,
                            'jml_jamkerja'  => isset($formatted_jam['Jml Jam Kerja']) ? $formatted_jam['Jml Jam Kerja'] : null,
                            'pengecualian'  => null,
                            'hci'           => null,
                            'hco'           => null,
                            'id_departement'=> $karyawan->divisi,
                            'h_normal'      => null,
                            'ap'            => null,
                            'hl'            => null,
                            'jam_kerja'     => isset($formatted_jam['Jml Kehadiran']) ? $formatted_jam['Jml Kehadiran'] : null,
                            'lemhanor'      => null,
                            'lemakpek'      => null,
                            'lemhali'       => null,                
                        ];
                        //  dd($data);
                        $absensi = Absensi::create($data);
                        // dd($absensi,$row);
                        $this->jumlahdatadiimport++;
                        Log::info('Data '. $row['NIK'] . $row['Tanggal']. ' berhasil di import ke database Absensi');    
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    $this->datatidakbisadiimport++;
                    Log::info('Data '. $row['NIK'] . $row['Tanggal']. ' sudah ada di sistem');    
                }

            }
            else
            {
                $this->datatidakbisadiimport++;
                Log::info('Karyawan '. $row['Emp No.'] . ' tidak terdaftar di sistem');
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $this->datatidakbisadiimport++;
            $this->jumlahdata++;
            Log::info('NIK karyawan kosong');
        }
        // dd($rowDataAssoc['Emp No.'],$rowDataAssoc['Nama'],$rowDataAssoc['Scan Pulang'],$rowDataAssoc['Jml Jam Kerja']);
    }
}

public function getJumlahData()
{
    return $this->jumlahdata;
}
public function getJumlahDataDiimport()
{
    return $this->jumlahdatadiimport;
}
 
//jumlah data yang diimport ke tabel tidak masuk
public function getDataImportTidakMasuk()
{
    return $this->jumlahimporttidakmasuk;
}
 
public function getDatatTidakBisaDiimport()
{
    return $this->datatidakbisadiimport;
}
```

}

I don't know where the issue lies, as this function is only importing one data entry into the database at a time. After one data entry is successfully imported, the subsequent data entries are not being processed.